# Как вывести через alert переменную?

Tags: javascript

Как вывести через alert переменную, что-то типа

```
window.alert(var $blabla);
```

Чтобы выскочило окошко со значением этой переменной.

Comment: из пхп в жабаскрипт надо? в этом проблема (судя по доллару)?

Answer (score 3):

```
myvar='бла бла'
alert (myvar);
```

Comment: капитан очевидность у нас на сайте! :)

Answer (score 1):

из **PHP:**

```
<?$blabla='некое значение';?>
<script>
alert('<?=$blabla?>');
</script>
```

из **JS:**

```
<script>
$blabla='некое значение';
alert($blabla);
</script>
```